# Time Dilation and Particle Decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, relativity, time-dilation

I am teaching myself astronomy and I'm working on a basic problem regarding time dilation around black holes.

The question is basically this: if a neutron were ejected from a nucleus at a distance of 3km from a 1 solar mass black hole, how long would it appear to take for the neutron to decay (the assumption here is that the neutron would decay in 15 minutes... right on the half-life) to an outside observer?

My first thought was that we'd never see it decay, because 3km is the Schwarzschild radius of a BH of that mass, so the frequency would basically be $0$ and we'd never observe the decay event.

The text notes the time dilation

$$
\frac{\Delta t'}{\Delta t_\text{obs}} = \frac{\nu_f}{\nu_i}$$
where $\Delta t'$ is the the time difference between two events at the source and $\Delta t_{obs}$ at the observer.

We can use the relativistic red shift equation to get the wavelength difference (9.2 in my case using 1 solar mass and a radius of 3km) so that wouldn't be infinite, just big. For a 15 min $\Delta t'$ then, the $\Delta t_{obs}$ would be 15 min * 9.2, yeah?

So my two answers obviously contradict each other. What am I missing in my approach here?

Comment: How did you get 9.2?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Please mark up your math using mathjax.

Comment: Thx Ben. On it.

Comment: The 9.2 comes from this equation:

$\frac {\lambda_f}{\lambda_i} = [1 - \frac{2GM}{Rc^2}]^{-1/2}$

using a radius of 3km and a mass of $2\times 10^{30}kg$

Comment: Your calculation of $9.2$ is wrong. If the event is on the Schwarzschild radius the gravitational time dilation is infinity. In the formula you have a zero at the denominator.

Comment: Ah, I was using $R=3km$, the radius of the blackhole rather than R being the distance from the neutron to the "surface". So you're saying that R is the two objects rather than the size of the primary object (the black hole in this case?

Comment: If you evaluate on the horizon $R = r_s = 2GM/c^2$, so the denominator is zero. ($r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius). A less approximated value for the Sun Schwarzschild radius is 2.953 km (The Astronomical Almanac Online for the year 2016, asa.usno.navy.mil/SecK/Constants.html).